# Is hadoop 1.0.4 the single cluster deprecated?

Tags: hadoop

As the question states it can not find any site to install it .I need the tar.gz version of it to install on my MAC.
Thanks in advance!
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get *tar.gz* Hadoop packages over [here](http://mirror.23media.de/apache/hadoop/common/). And 1.0.4 is [here](https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-1.0.4/).